# How to add a border for an image like this using php GD

Tags: php, facebook

I Came across a **facebook** app .The example image is given below.Can Some one help me how to add border to an image like below using simple **PHP** GD code.I saw some example to add border.But that code is quite large.

[image: example app]

Comment: By border you mean the polaroid style?

Comment: @DamienPirsy : yeas..that white colour

Comment: no one will give you code, learn to use google http://mjcarrascosa.com/efecto-polaroid-con-php-y-gd/ or write some code so we can help you.

Comment: I dont know that Effect name is POLAROID . Thank you..just now i came to know it.I will google for it